# I am trying to read input from 5th PIN of PORT B?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

In a nutshell i want to read a PORTB 5th pin without using digitalRead API ( i am trying to learn baremetal using arduino-uno-r3)

Just to Learn How internal register works i did not used digitalRead API, instead i have used DDRB register to set the 5 bit of DDRB as Low indicating PORTB 5th pin is in input mode then i am using an if statment to check if 5th bit of PINB is high or low my expection was that when i connect arduino pin 13 to 5v  if statment will become TRUE.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  DDRB = DDRB & ~(1<<5);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(PINB & (1<<5)){
     Serial.println("Got data"); 
    }
}
```

When i executed above code i am constantly getting if as TRUE

Comment: Do you use an external pullup or pulldown resistor?

Comment: your code is operating on the 6th bit ... bits are numbered 0 to 7, so 5th bit is bit 4

Comment: I have not used any pull up resistor and i am sure PINB 5th bit is 13 pin of aurdino

Comment: No, digital 13 is PB5, i.e. the 6th bit. The 1st bit is PB0, the 2nd bit is PB1, etc.

Comment: If nothing is connected to the pin then it can read either high or low.  Google “floating pin”.  If you’re expecting it to read low when not connected to anything then you’re thinking wrong.

Comment: @EdgarBonet so what should i change in code

Comment: @Delta_G then what is the point of low and high if pin is always (floating ) high

Comment: http://www.electronoobs.com/images/Arduino/tut_31/arduino_uno_scheamtic.png PB5 IS 13TH PIN ON ARDUINO i think i am correct

Comment: It's not 13th pin, it's pin “digital 13”. Not the same.

Comment: The point is that if the pin is tied to a voltage it will read that voltage.  If it is unconnected then what voltage is on the pin?  If you answer zero then you need to go and study basic electronics some more.  A pin should read LOW when it is connected to ground and HIGH when connected to 5V.  If it is unconnected then you don't know what the voltage level at the pin is.  It can pick up any stray noise and read anything.

Comment: The point is, "Don't try to read a pin that isn't connected to anything."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be several, separate issues in your question.

One is a simple matter of language. In English, “1st” is an abbreviation
for “first”, which is an ordinal adjective applied to an item in a list
meaning that there is no other item before it in that list. In the same
vein, “5th” means “fifth”, which applies to the item that has exactly
four items before it. For instance, the list of pins of port B is {PB0,
PB1, PB2, PB3, PB4, PB5}. PB0 is the first in the list, and PB4 is the
fifth. The fact the first item bears the number 0 makes this confusing.
Thus, I recommend avoiding ordinal adjectives altogether and instead
calling the pins by their names, like “digital 13” (Arduino naming) or
“PB5” (AVR naming).

The second issue, and probably your main concern, is about the floating
input pin. You cannot expect a reliable reading from a floating input. I
will not try to explain why, as the issue has been discussed ad nauseam
here and elsewhere. Just do a Web search. The simplest solution is to
use the built-in pull-up resistor and externally connect a push button
between the pin and ground. You will read `LOW` whenever the button is
pressed:

```cpp
void setup() {
    pinMode(13, INPUT_PULLUP);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if (digitalRead(13) == HIGH)
        Serial.println("HIGH");
    else
        Serial.println("LOW");
}
```

The last point is about going bare metal and learning how to use the I/O
registers directly. A small warning first: you have to keep in mind that
this is board-specific. You tagged your question with both “arduino-uno”
and “arduino-mega”, but these boards have different pin mappings
(digital 13 is PB7 on the Mega). The general way of using the DDRx,
PORTx and PINx registers is the same across all AVR chips, but is not
portable to Arduinos based on a different architecture.

So let's assume this is intended to work only on an Uno, Nano, or
other board based on an ATmega328P.
Judging from the example code you show, you seem to
already understand pretty well how these registers work. There is no
problem in your code, beside the fact that it requires an external
pull-up. If you want to enable the internal pull-up, you have to set the
appropriate bit in PORTB. This can seem confusing, as the same register
is used for pull-up control (when the pin is in input mode) and for
output control (when the pin is an output). Essentially, each GPIO pin
has four distinct electrical states which are controlled by to I/O bits:

```
│ DDRxn │ PORTxn │ state        │
├───────┼────────┼──────────────┤
│   0   │    0   │ INPUT        │
│   0   │    1   │ INPUT_PULLUP │
│   1   │    0   │ OUTPUT LOW   │
│   1   │    1   │ OUTPUT HIGH  │
└───────┴────────┴──────────────┘
```

The example program above can be translated to low-level AVR style as
follows:

```cpp
void setup() {
    DDRB &= ~_BV(PB5);  // input mode
    PORTB |= _BV(PB5);  // enable pullup
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if (PINB & _BV(PB5))
        Serial.println("HIGH");
    else
        Serial.println("LOW");
}
```

Comment: Nicely put @edgar.  I might add a comment (as the OP did say he/she wanted to do bare metal programming) that different Arduinos board can contain different processors.  And  what works here in this answer is for a specific processor.  And that other processors can and most often work very differently.

Comment: @st2000: Good point. Edited the answer.